# CORS support on sonarqube 6.2 web-services

Tags: sonarqube

When I try to access a sonar web service from a local server (http://localhost:8383/), I am getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error.   The init-param for **RackFilter** , **resetUnhandledResponse** is already false in web.xm. 
How to enable CORS for Sonar Web Services?

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube does not support CORS. You should either access SonarQube Web API from the server side, or use a reverse-proxy that would allow for CORS.

Comment: Why would you develop a web api that cannot be called from javascript?